Solving the Dirichlet problem in a rectangular region with the following boundary conditions:
We want to solve $\Delta u = 0$ in the rectangle $R = \{(x,y): 0 \leq x \leq \pi, 0 \leq y \leq 1\}$ satisfying the boundary conditions:
$u(x,0) = f_0(x)$, where $f_0(x)= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{A_k\sin(kx)}$:
$u(x,1) = f_1(x)$, where $f_1(x)= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{B_k\sin(kx)}$
$u(0,y) = u(0, \pi) = 0$.
Okay, using separation of variables, I got the following:
$X'' - \lambda X= 0$ and $Y'' + \lambda Y = 0$. Define $\lambda = -m^2$. For the first equation, the solution is $X(x) = A\cos(mx) + B\sin(mx)$, which after applying boundary conditions, $A = 0$, so we have that $X(x) = B\sin(mx)$.
The second equation has solution $Y(y) = \overline{C} e^{my} + \overline{D} e^{-my}$, which after much rearranging, you can make look like $Y(y) = C\cosh(my) + D\sinh(my)$.
Since $u(x,y) = X(x)Y(y)$, I got $u(x,y) = (BC\cosh(my) + BD\sinh(my))\sin(mx)$. I need a little guidance on how to apply the remaining boundary conditions to get the answer to look like:
$u(x,y) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{(\frac{\sinh(k(1-y))}{\sinh(k)}A_k + \frac{\sinh(ky)}{\sinh(k)}B_k)\sin(kx) }$

Finally figured it out. First, remember that we actually have $u(x,y) = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}{(V_m\cosh(my)+W_m\sinh(my))\sin(mx)}$, where I defined $V_m = B_mC_m$ and $W_m = B_mD_m$, since the functions $X(x)$ and $Y(y)$ should actually be $X_m(x)$ and $Y_m(x)$.
Okay, so plugging in the first boundary condition, we get that $u(x,0) = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}{V_m\sin(mx)} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{A_k\sin(kx)}$, so to find $V_m$, we can use the formula for the Fourier coefficients, namely: $V_m = \int_{0}^{\pi}{A_k\sin(kx)\sin(mx){dx}} = A_k$ only when $k=m$. Thus, we have $V_m = A_m$.
Plugging in the second boundary condition, we find that $u(x,1) = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}{(A_m\cosh(m)+W_m\sinh(m))\sin(mx)} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{B_k\sin(kx)}$, which similarly gets us that $W_m = \frac{B_m - A_m\cosh(m)}{\sinh(m)}$.
Plugging everything in to $u(x,y) = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}{(V_m\cosh(my)+W_m\sinh(my))\sin(mx)}$, we see that $u(x,y) = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}{[A_m(\cosh(my)\sinh(m) - \cosh(m)\sinh(my)) + B_m(\frac{\sinh(my)}{\sinh(m)})]\sin(mx)}$, or $u(x,y) = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}{[A_m(\sinh(m-my) + B_m(\frac{\sinh(my)}{\sinh(m)})]\sin(mx)}$, using an identify for the hyperbolic functions.
